# heroku memcachier for multiple rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, heroku

Can we use same MEMCACHIER config variables for multiple rails apps for my heroku account.

like I have a app1 that using MEMCACHIER. I have also another app2 (child app of app1) and this app2 having some common cache keys or some separate keys. So can we use single MEMCACHIER for both apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! The easiest way is to simply provision MemCachier on one of the apps and then setup corresponding environment variables in the other app. I.e.,

```
$ heroku addons:add memcachier:1000
$ heroku config:get
```

Then copy the variables, `MEMCACHIER_USERNAME`, `MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD` and `MEMCACHIER_SERVERS` and set them up in the corresponding Heroku app.

You can also simply provision a MemCachier cache directly from MemCachier through their [website](http://www.memcachier.com/). Then you would setup the config variables for both apps and have a nice advantage that your cache isn't tied to either of them. So if you killed both apps, your cache would still be alive and can be managed separately.